# Make time auto shutoff PC fan - safe?

Tags: voltage

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fILnrY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am making a fan that shuts off after a minute or two, but is this circuit safe for the fan? It runs at full power at first, but as the caps discharge, the fan should slow down and eventually stop when the caps are fully discharged. The button resets the circuit.

Comment: The current directions through the transistors don't make sense. You seem to expect currents to flow against the voltage and do loopy-de-loops through the transistors. In particular you seem to expect current to flow against the voltage in most terminals of Q1.

Comment: If the answer to a control problem seems to be "use a 2 mF capacitor", then the real answer is probably "use a modern timer IC (usually not the 555) or some other clever form of control, e.g. a cheap microcontroller"

Comment: what happens if you connect PWM to GND?

Comment: I edited the post, so Q1's GND is connected directly to the negative terminal of the batteries.

Comment: In this case, I really don't quite understand how this circuit is intended to work (you're not telling us anything about the design methodology), but I can assure you that the price of a 2 mF capacitor plus a pushbutton that will repeatedly withstand breaking the inrush current into such a beast will be much higher than that of a microcontroller and a cheap pushbutton that really only carries a tiny signaling current.

Comment: There is a 10K resistor to prevent the surge.

Comment: It might not be safe for whatever the fan is supposed to cool.

Comment: The 10k is limiting the base current. Is the pushbutton that will have arcing at its contacts. Why not PWM control the fan as intended?

Comment: Please clarify - is the "2 mF" capacitor supposed to be 2 microfarads, as in 2 uF, 2000 microfarads ( 2 m microfarads), or 2000 farads 2 m farads)? Please spell it out.  Note that none of these choices works out to a 1-2 minute delay.

Comment: I don't see how the 10 kOhm resistor limits the current through the button into the directly adjacent capacitor? Let's face it: this circuit doesn't really do what you want, it would help if your question explained why you chose the components and topology you chose. Maybe it'd be easier to help you then!

Comment: @AnalogKid how do you get 2000 farads from 2 mF?

Comment: I was guessing at what the OP might mean.  I guess a better guess would be 2 millifarads, or 2000 uF, for a time constant of 20 seconds and an ON time of around 50 seconds.

Comment: @Transistor You can't set ON time with PWM. That only sets the **speed**.

Comment: @ssr215, PWM = 0% gives speed = 0, PWM = 100% gives speed = 100%. If it's working at 100% with PWM floating then you probably just need to pull PWM to GND for 0 **speed**.

Comment: @Transistor, what I mean by ON time is to turn on for x minutes, then stop. Pressing the button restarts the time delay. PWM only controls the speed of the fan.

Comment: @ssr215, I understood that from your original question. You are not realising that the solution is much simpler when you use the built-in control function to switch on and off by time instead of switching the power. You can most likely do ON/OFF control using the PWM input without the risk of burning your switch contacts and with a relatively tiny capacitor.

Comment: @jstola, I want to cut power to the fan to save battery when the set time expires. Turning off the fan with PWM does NOT save battery.

Comment: @ssr215 it does. You're clearly out of your depth here, ssr215.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your previous question, you're beginning to get into "use a microprocessor" territory.

That said, the 555 is once again your friend. This IC comes in a 2-per package called the 556, and it's available in CMOS as the TLC556. Use one of them for your one-shot timer, and the other to make your PWM speed.

Basically,

- timer ON: run PWM at setting
- timer OFF: force PWM to 0%

The TLC556 datasheet is here: https://www.ti.com/product/TLC556

When you get tired of that, consider using something like an ATTiny.

Also, another idea: when the fan PWM is low, that stops the fan. If that's all you care about (assuming you gave up on the speed control idea) the circuit gets a lot simpler since you're only dealing with a logic input rather than switching power off. Still, the 555 will work better, especially for such a long time.

Even better, consider the CD4060 ripple counter. Then you're not dealing with stupidly-large capacitors for the long delays.